# jQuery several external HTML elements under a single DIV container

Tags: jquery, html, replace, load

my goal is to load three distinct *div* elements from an external HTML and insert it under the same *div* container of the parent HTML by using jQuery.

Currently, my code looks as follows (external HTML, excerpt):

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Main.</div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">Right.</div>
    <div id="legendcolumn">Legend.</div>
 </div>
```

And I would like to insert all three *div* elements under *div id="inserted"* into the parent HTML. In jQuery I found the *load()* function. However, it replaces all the content under the element and does not append it.

```
$("#inserted").load("external.html #wrapper");
```

This code replaces all previous elements under *body*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) ajax functions instead of the `.load()` function, which was designed to do one thing and one thing only. Your code will look something like this:

```
$.get('external.html', function(data){
    $(data).find('#wrapper > div').appendTo('#inserted');
});
```

`external.html` will be accessible through the `data` variable, so we wrap it with the jQuery function, then find the elements we need before appending them to the correct element in the current page.